# How to get Synaptics Touchpad working under Ubuntu Mate 19.04

Tags: touchpad, thinkpad, mate, 19.04, synaptics

The Synaptics-touchpad on my [ThinkPad L580](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/l580_hmm_en.pdf) doesn't work with Ubuntu (Mate) 19.04, even though I've followed instructions that seem to have worked for other people in the past.

In the following snippets there is a Microsoft USB-mouse attached.

`xinput --list`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Optical Mouse                         id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

`cat /proc/bus/input/devices`:
    No synaptics related stuff showing up...

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 06cb:009a Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b604 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 045e:0797 Microsoft Corp. Optical Mouse 200
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this seemingly identical bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1825699/) on launchpad you can fix this by passing

```
psmouse.elantech_smbus=0
```

to the boot options.

Take a look at [How do I add a kernel boot parameter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter) if you need information as to how to add boot options.